# Simple margin property is displayed properly in IE and FireFox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css

The two main container blocks (the one with the square tiles/menu items)
and the top block above are of the same width and line up properly in all
browsers other than Chrome.

This is caused by Chrome not rendering the following margin property
accurately for some reason. Putting the margin-right at 4px sort
of gets it the correct width, but this will break the layout in Explorer and FireFox.
Have no idea what's causing it. See fiddle for live example. Just stretch the frames out
to see the whole thing.

```
 DIV.RootCell
{
 width: 134px;
 height: 120px;
 margin-right: 3px;     //<-------------
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHxsS/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Firefox and Chrome are off by 1 px for me.  The issue I see is this:

The top box is declared to be 937px wide.

The grid below has 7 elements in it.  Each is 134 px wide with a 3px right-margin.  That means you get (134x7) + (3x6) as the visible width.  When you do the math, that comes out to 956px wide which is one short of the declared with for the top box.  If you make the top box be 936px, it should work in both Chrome and Firefox.

And, you can see that change work in both Chrome and Firefox here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bdP8p/1/

Also, check your browser zoom level and make sure it's at 100%.  I noticed that your layout is sensitive to the browser zoom as it goes off by a bunch when you zoom in or out (anything other than 100%).

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am using an older or newer Chrome version. It's off by a good 4-5px for me in Chrome. In your example I see no change in my Chrome browser (17.0.963.79 m).

Comment: @LaserBeak - I'm running Chrome 17 here.  The fixed version works here in Safari, Firefox and Opera too.  It has a bunch of other display issues in IE9 (borders that aren't working properly).

Comment: @LaserBeak - check your browser zoom level.  I noticed that in Chrome, your layout goes off by more when the browser zoom is not 100%.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not handling zooming well. Anything I can do to improve this? Maybe give something a fixed width or something.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, though I am not using borders at all. So not sure what you are seeing wrong in IE

Comment: And it is in fact Chrome and Safari (WebKit) not handling the zooming well, especially at 125%. IE and FireFox do fine.

Comment: @LaserBeak - I'd have to study your layout to figure out why it's zoom-sensitive.  I'm not sure what causes it after a quick look.

Comment: IE sometimes has default borders on things like images that can mess things up if you aren't specifying enough CSS.

Comment: And sensetive only to webkit based browsers it seems ie. Chrome and Safari